# How do I emulate a "fake" external USB drive?

Tags: windows, usb, emulation, external-drive

My goal is to create a disk partition that my Windows computer recognises as a removable device, but is actually a virtual hard disk.

Answer (score 2):

I've searched for a while, finding similar questions with partial answers (with this being the closest: [Is there software to fully emulate a USB hard drive?](https://superuser.com/questions/391679/is-there-software-to-fully-emulate-a-usb-hard-drive))
However, none of them clearly answered my question.

Goal: To create a disk partition that my Windows computer recognises as a removable device, but is actually a virtual hard disk.

1. In the start menu, search for "disk management" and click on "Create and format hard disk partitions". Wait for it to load - this may take a few seconds.
2. In the toolbar go to `Action > Create VHD`.
3. Set the location to wherever you want to place the virtual hard disk on your local file system. You have to specify the filename, not just the location. This means `C:/MyContainingFolder` would be wrong, and `C:/MyContainingFolder/virtualusb.vhd` would be correct.
4. Specify the "Virtual hard disk size" to be however big you want your USB drive to be.
   *NOTE: I have only tested this with the VHD format for a 64GB fixed size drive. This should work for different sized drives, but my instincts tell me that a variable size hard disk might confuse the system when mounted as removeable storage.*
5. Once this VHD (virtual hard drive) has been created, you should see it in the disk management screen. Right click and click "Intialize disk" and select the `MBR (Master Boot Record)` partition style.
   *Note: GPT may work, but again I've only tested with MBR.*
6. Right-click on "Unallocated" and select "New Simple Volume..." and create a new simple volume, and follow the simple volume creation wizard to completion.
7. Go to File Explorer and right-click -> "Eject" the volume.
8. Install ImDisk. I got my version from SourceForge, but since I haven't verified or tested the file I'm not going to link it here. Windows Defender detected no issues as of 01/12/2023.
9. Navigate to where you installed ImDisk (default is `C:/Program Files/ImDisk`) and run `MountImg.exe`. It will require administrator privileges.
10. For "Image File", enter the location of your .vhd file (e.g. `C:/MyContainingFolder/virtualusb.vhd`)
11. Assign a drive letter of your choice, tick the "Removable" box, and keep the device type as "Hard Disk". Press "OK", et voila!

I hope people find this helpful!

I'm writing these steps mostly from memory, as I don't like to faff around with disk partitions just for the sake of a tutorial. For the first 6 steps, I used the following resource to both create my virtual hard drive, and as a reference for this guide:
https://bardimin.com/en/windows-en/how-to-create-a-virtual-usb-flash-drive-in-windows-10/

Comment: Great self-answered question!